# Как работает solve?

Tags: python, математика, sympy

Я закидываю уравнение в метод solve, метод возвращает список формул:

```
[-3.08250265220643 + 0.e-21*I, 0.204826458650812 - 0.366241504255597*I, 0.204826458650812 + 0.366241504255597*I, 1.21696879784 + 0.e-21*I]
```

Не очень понимаю как из этого получить переменную которую искал. Нужно подстановкой число, чтобы везде 0 получилось. Или как это работает?

Библиотека sympy. Я закинул в метод уравнение с одним неизвестным, как мне получить неизвестное?

Уравнение имеет вид:

```
(self.f+self.k)*self.s**4+4*(1-self.k*self.f)*self.s**3+2\
           *(self.k*self.f**2-3*self.f-2*self.k)*self.s**2+4*self.f*\
           (self.f+self.k)*self.s+self.f-self.k-2*self.k*self.f**2
```

неизвестное s.

k,s- в процессе заменяется числами

Comment: о какой библиотеке идет речь?

Comment: решение вашего уравнения содержит четыре корня - два реальных и два комплексных. Можете уточнить суть вашего вопроса?

Comment: @MaxU, дописал!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас полином 4-й степени:

```
f(x) = (F+K)*x**4 + 4*(1-K*F)*x**3 + 2*(K*F**2 - 3*F-2*K)*x**2 + 4*F*(F+K)*x + F - K-2*K*F**2
```

который в общем случае имеет 4-е корня.

Соответственно `solve()` вернул вам список всех корней данного уравнения.

---

Как проверить корни уравнения:

```
In [26]: F=0.46630765815499864; K=0.9999999999999999

In [27]: x = Symbol('x')

In [28]: f = (F+K)*x**4 + 4*(1-K*F)*x**3 + 2*(K*F**2 - 3*F-2*K)*x**2 + 4*F*(F+K)*x + F - K-2*K*F**2

In [29]: roots = solve(f, x)

In [30]: roots
Out[30]:
[-3.08250265220643 + 0.e-21*I,
 0.204826458650812 - 0.366241504255597*I,
 0.204826458650812 + 0.366241504255597*I,
 1.21696879784 + 0.e-21*I]

In [31]: f.evalf(subs={x:roots[3]})
Out[31]: -1.55991589742868e-14 + 1.23734514514385e-20*I
```

Comment: А I это корень из -1. Или что?

Comment: @chilo5432, ну да - это крень из `-1`... А `0.e-21` - можно считать нулем - соответственно у вас два вещественных и два комплексных корня уравнения

Comment: Чтобы мне получить числовой ответ. Я должен подставить место I либо 1 либо -1. Так ведь?

Comment: что вы понимаете под числовым ответом? Вы хотите получить только вещественные корни и игнорировать комплексные?

Comment: Все до меня дошло. Большое спасибо

Comment: Я тут не могу разобраться. А как I заменить то через subs не получается?

Comment: @chilo5432, его нельзя заменить - это не переменная это конкретное число - `sqrt(-1)`

Comment: А как тогда поставить в уравнение это число?

Comment: @chilo5432, `roots = solve(f, x); res = f(roots[1])` ?

Comment: Не могу понять, что такое, res = f(roots[1]). Ну типо у нас есть формула: 1.21696879784 + 0.e-21*I и как в ней заменить I???? print(s[3].subs('I',0))-не работает((

Comment: @chilo5432, `I` - это уже конкретное число его нельзя заменить. Ваш вопрос сродни такому: `Как мне заменить число 243 на 0?`. Для каких значений `self.f`и `self.k` вы нашли данные корни?

Comment: f=0.46630765815499864 k=0.9999999999999999, нужный ответ я получаю в последнем ответе

Comment: @chilo5432, `"нужный ответ я получаю в последнем ответе"` - какие у вас критерии выбора нужного ответа?